# How to insert php variable into mysql query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have the following statement:

```
 SELECT bname,cnum,vnum, MATCH(vtext) AGAINST (''".$word."'') as relevance FROM kjv  WHERE MATCH(vtext) AGAINST (''".$word."'') AND bnum='".$book."' ORDER by relevance DESC, bnum, cnum, vnum LIMIT 0,1");
```

which returns empty rows, but if I substitute the variables with hardcoded values, everything goes through. The variables are not null, I know because I output them to the page after I type them in a box. Thanks

Comment: Whether you can get it to work or not, this method of directly concatenating strings into a SQL command is *very* insecure.  *Never* treat input as code and blindly execute it against the database.  Use prepared statements instead, which treat the input as values instead of code: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to see more of the surrounding code, but I expect it's the double single quotes causing the problem:

```
SELECT bname,cnum,vnum, MATCH(vtext) AGAINST ('".$word."') as relevance FROM kjv  WHERE MATCH(vtext) AGAINST ('".$word."') AND bnum='".$book."' ORDER by relevance DESC, bnum, cnum, vnum LIMIT 0,1");
```

Comment: This answer fixes the problem at hand, but fails to address the more pressing concerns (SQL injection, the advantage of using parametrized queries...) An answer that handles *those* I would upvote :)

Comment: Downvoted for obvious reasons. Please use parameterized queries!

Answer (score 0):

Hi Try This if you already saved value in variable.

```
 SELECT bname,cnum,vnum, MATCH(vtext) AGAINST ('$word') as relevance FROM kjv    WHERE MATCH(vtext) AGAINST ('$word') AND bnum='".$book."' ORDER by relevance DESC, bnum, cnum, vnum LIMIT 0,1");
```

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
mysql_query("SELECT bname,cnum,vnum, MATCH(vtext) AGAINST($word) as relevance FROM kjv  WHERE MATCH(vtext) AGAINST ($word) AND bnum='$book' ORDER by relevance DESC, bnum, cnum, vnum LIMIT 0,1");
```

Answer (score -1):

Try like this:

```
SELECT bname,cnum,vnum, MATCH(vtext) AGAINST ("$word") as relevance
FROM kjv  WHERE MATCH(vtext) AGAINST ("$word") AND bnum= "$book" 
ORDER by relevance DESC, bnum, cnum, vnum LIMIT 0,1");
```